# Looping through items in dataframe while using apply function

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has 104 items ("items1" --> "items104"). Each item was administered at different ages, so "items1" for instance is divided into columns items1.12, items1.18, items1.24, items1.30, items1.36. This is the case for all 104 items. I would like to run the following code on each of the 104 items in the dataframe.

```
ID <- c("4000", "4001", "4006", "4007", "4009", "4010")
items1.12 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
items1.18 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
items1.24 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
items1.30 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
items1.36 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

items2.12 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)
items2.18 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)
items2.24 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)
items2.30 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)
items2.36 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)
wide <- data.frame(ID, items1.12, items1.18, items1.24, items1.30, items1.36, items2.12, items2.18, items2.24, items2.30, items2.36)
```

```
ID   items1.12 items1.18 items1.24 items1.30 items1.36 items2.12 items2.18 items2.24 items2.30 items2.36
4000         1         1         1         1         1         2         2         2         2         2
4001         1         1         1         1         1         2         2         2         2         2
4006         1         1         1         NA        1         1         1         1         1         1
4007         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
4009         1         1         1         1         1         2         2         2         2         2
4010         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
```

I would like to run this code for each item. Here is an example for "items1"

```
wide$items1.new <- apply(!is.na(wide[,paste("items1.", c(12,18,24,30,36), sep = "")]), 1, max)
wide$items1.new.2 <- NA
for(i in unique(wide$ID)){
  select <- i == wide$ID
  ifelse(wide$items1.new[select] == 0, wide$items1.new.2 [select] <- NA, wide$items1.new.2[select] <- rowMeans(wide[select,c("items1.12", "items1.18", "items1.24", "items1.30", "items1.36")], na.rm = T))}
wide <- subset(wide, select = -c(items1.new, items1.12, items1.18, items1.24, items1.30, items1.36))
names(wide)[names(wide) == 'items1.new.2'] <- "item1"
```

Here is an example for "items2"

```
wide$items2.new <- apply(!is.na(wide[,paste("items2.", c(12,18,24,30,36), sep = "")]), 1, max)
wide$items2.new.2 <- NA
for(i in unique(wide$ID)){
  select <- i == wide$ID
  ifelse(wide$items2.new[select] == 0, wide$items2.new.2 [select] <- NA, wide$items2.new.2[select] <- rowMeans(wide[select,c("items2.12", "items2.18", "items2.24", "items2.30", "items2.36")], na.rm = T))}
wide <- subset(wide, select = -c(items2.new, items2.12, items2.18, items2.24, items2.30, items2.36))
names(wide)[names(wide) == 'items2.new.2'] <- "item2"
```

Here is what I would like to end with:

```
ID   item1 item2
4000     1     2
4001     1     2
4006     1     1
4007     1     1
4009     1     2
4010     1     1
```

I would like to do this for items1 to items104 in my dataset. I can't imagine the solution would be very complicated, but I would really appreciate some help as I'm new to R. Thank you so much.

Comment: First, make your data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) by converting to long format.  Second, help yourself by helping us to help you by providing both test data and the expected output based on that test data.

Comment: I went ahead and provided test data as well as the expected output. The data needs to stay in wide format because of the nature of my task.

Comment: Just because your result needs to be in wide format doesn't need the data needs to stay in wide format. It's often much easier to pivot to long, do grouped operations, pivot back to wide, than to try to keep it in wide format the whole time.

Comment: Understood. The problem is that this data is part of a larger data frame that is in wide format, so converting from wide to long then back to wide is going to be a hassle. I'm simply trying to combine all of those columns for each item into one column, as shown above. I wrote the code to do it for one item, but I don't know how to apply it to all the items.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, this can be done with `split.default`

```
 cbind(wide['ID'], sapply(split.default(wide[-1],
   sub("\\.\\d+$", "" , names(wide)[-1])), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
     ID items1 items2
1 4000      1      2
2 4001      1      2
3 4006      1      1
4 4007      1      1
5 4009      1      2
6 4010      1      1
```